# Анализы: берутся или проводятся?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Пишу текст по лабораторным исследованиям. Но меня озадачило вот что. Анализы берутся или анализы проводятся? Или может быть и то, и другое?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Берутся образцы или пробы для анализа. Берутся анализы - просторечие.

Answer (score 4):

Я так понимаю, что и берутся, когда у пациента берут кровь, например, и проводятся, когда потом в лаборатории анализируется состав этой крови. Хотя правильнее было бы, наверное, сказать, не анализы берутся, а кровь на анализ.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от смысла. Анализы-пробы, включая медицинские, берутся ("отбор проб" в геологии). 
Это не просторечие, скорее - разговорное.